# Control animation looping in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to loop an animation in phaser3 a specified number of times.  The user provides input which is assigned to a 'loopTimes' variable. I have tried to make that variable control the number of loops two different ways, neither of which seem to work.

The first way is in the button push function using a while loop:

```
totalButton.on('pointerdown', function () {
            loopTimes = varCountOne + varCountTwo;
            totalText.setText(loopTimes);
            var i = 0;
            while (i < loopTimes) {
                horse.anims.play('numerate');
                i++;
            }

        });
```

This results in the animation looping once even when loopTimes is 10 (I have had it print the i value to the console to make sure it is counting correctly).

The second way is to use the loopTimes variable in the animation:

```
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'numerate',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', {start: 0, end: 3}),
            frameRate: 10, 
            repeat: loopTimes
        });
```

This also resulted in the loop happening once even when loopTimes was greater than one.  I suspect that I am missing something fairly obvious, but since I am new to both javascript and phaser it is not obvious to me.

thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell you're doing it correctly in the `second way`, I'm looking at [this example from the docs](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src\animation\animation%20repeat%20event.js) which works nicely. **What version of Phaser are you using?**

Comment: Phaser 3. I also saw that example and assumed it would work. Is there any reason to think that the repeat can't take a variable? loopTimes is defined in the totalButton function, which itself triggers the numerate animation. When I manually set repeat to '10' it repeats 10 times, but when it is 'loopTimes' it just repeats once no matter how big the loopTimes variable is.

Comment: Update: if I define a variable at the top of the script and set it to 10, then use the variable in the second way, it loops the 10 times.  So I think the issue is that loopTimes being set in the totalButton function is not making it to the animation loop.  I strongly suspect that this is some obvious global/local variable issue, but I don't know enough about basic javascript to be able to fix it.

Comment: Are you attempting to change the loopTimes variable more than once? Like every time a user clicks a button it prompts for a new value? Or is it a one-time event?

Comment: More than once.  The user sets two variables (that's the varCountOne and varCountTwo) and then clicks the totalButton to make the animation loop a number of times based on those variables.